# Cancel Android Notification with an action

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I coded an app to create and remove notifications, as a notice for something.

Now I don't want to remove all notifications at once (with cancelAll()).
The notifications get a random ID, so that you can create more than one notification.
But that is the problem.
How can I use the nMgr.cancel(HELLO_ID) for each notification with the random created id? (The id is "saved" in the integer "HELLO_ID")

Set notifiaction:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_icon)
            .setContentTitle(titelText.getText())
            .setContentText(beschreibungText.getText())
            .addAction(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha, "Remove!", removeNotification);
```

Random ID:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    final int HELLO_ID = rand.nextInt(100);
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

And also, would be this the action to call from the .addAction?

```
private PendingIntent removeNotification;

public MainActivity(PendingIntent removeNotification) {
    this.removeNotification = removeNotification;

    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nMgr.cancel();
}
```